# Visualforce Email template not creating attachment

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, attachment, visualforce-template

I have a VisualForce template for an email, and this also has a PDF attachment similar to the email itself. When I run the **Send Test and Verify Merge Fields** it creates it fine, populates the fields and creates the attachment.

I've created a URL hack button to pass the Order, email address and other related info, and when I click this button on the Order it generates the email no problem, but not the attachment.

If I then select the same template from the **Select Template** option, it regenerates the email and then does create the attachment.

Why doesn't it create it from the button?? Help! It used to work before I defaulted the recipient email address, but now even if I remove that from the button hack it still doesn't work.

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003
&p3_lkid={!Order.Id}
&retURL=%2F{!Order.Id}
&p5={!$User.Email}
&p2_lkid={!Order.CustomerAuthorizedById}
&template_id=00XO0000000Ek5M
```

And my VF template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Return Authorisation #: 
{!relatedTo.OrderNumber}" recipientType="Contact" 
replyTo="sales@xxx.co.nz" relatedToType="Order">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
    <style>
        body { 
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif}

        table, th, td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>        
    <body>          
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1" style="font-size:10px; text-align:right">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center><img src='https://c.cs5.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015O0000000n8WP&oid=00DO0000000VuvS&lastMod=1465879820000' title="logo" /></center>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <apex:outputText value="Date: {0,date,dd' 'MMMM', 'yyyy}" styleClass="tright">
                        <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />
                    </apex:outputText><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {!relatedTo.Email_Notes__c}<br/><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Return Authorisation #: {!relatedTo.OrderNumber}</b>
                    <br/><br/>
                    Attached is your RMA (Return Maintenance Authority) return form as requested. Please print it and attach it to the parcel.
                    <br/><br/>
                    <strong>THE RMA NUMBER ABOVE MUST BE CLEARLY MARKED ON THE OUTSIDE OF THE PARCEL BEING RETURNED</strong>
                    <br/><br/>
                    Please ensure that the goods are sufficiently packaged to ensure that no damage occurs during transit.<br/><br/>
                    If you have any queries or, want to follow up on the collection relating to this return, please contact
                    xxx on <strong>0800 999999</strong> or email <strong><a href="mailto:sales@xxx.co.nz">sales@xxx.co.nz</a></strong>.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <hr/>
        </table>
        <!--Addresses -->
        <hr/>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table3">
            <tr>    
                <td width="48%">
                    <b>Customer Details:</b><br/>
                    <b>{!relatedTo.Account.Name}</b><br/>
                    {!relatedTo.BillingStreet}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.BillingPostalCode} {!relatedTo.BillingCity}
                    <br/><br/>
                    <b>Account Number: </b>{!relatedTo.Account.AccountNumber}<br/>
                </td>
                <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <b>Delivery Address for Return:</b><br/>
                    {!$Organization.Name}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.ShippingStreet}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.ShippingPostalCode} {!relatedTo.ShippingCity}
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <hr/>


        <table border="0" width="100%" id="table4" style="font-size:10px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Customer Contact name:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Contact email:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Email}<br/>
                    <b>Contact phone:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Phone}<br/><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <b>Created by:</b> {!relatedTo.CreatedBy.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Source Order :</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Order__r.OrderNumber}<br/>
                    <b>Source Invoice:</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Invoice__r.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Case:</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Document__c}
                </td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="table5" style="font-size:10px">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Product</h4></td>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Description</h4></td>
    <!--            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Image</h4></td>-->
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Quantity</h4></td>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Unit</h4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OrderItems}" var="line">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.ProductCode}</td>
                        <td>{!line.Description}</td>
    <!--                    <td ALIGN="center"><img src='{!line.PricebookEntry.Product2.URL_Picture__c}'/></td>             -->
                        <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>
                        <td>{!line.Unit__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>  
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->        
<messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" filename="{!relatedTo.name}">               
<html>
    <style>
        body { 
        font-size:10px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif}

        h2 {
        font-size:14px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        line-height: 16px}

        h3 {
        font-size:12px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        line-height: 14px }

        h4 {
        font-size:11px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        line-height:13px}

        table, th, td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th { font-weight: bold; }

        @page {
            counter-increment: pages;
            @top-center {content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);}
            @bottom-center {content: element(footer);}
        }
        div.footer {position: running(footer)}
        #pageNum: before {content: counter(pages);}
    </style>        
    <body>
        <div class="footer" style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center">
            <p align="center"><i>Copyright {!$Organization.Name}</i></p>

            <apex:outputText value="Printed: {! NOW() }"/>     
        </div>
        <!--Logo and RMA number -->
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.xxx)}' title="logo" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <hr/>
        </table>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This number must be attached to all items being returned<br/>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <h2>Return Authorisation #: {!relatedTo.OrderNumber}</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <hr/>
        </table>

        <!--Addresses -->
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
            <tr>    
                <td width="48%">
                    <h4>Customer Details</h4>
                    <h3>{!relatedTo.Account.Name}</h3>
                    {!relatedTo.BillingStreet}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.BillingPostalCode} {!relatedTo.BillingCity}
                    <br/><br/>
                    <b>Account Number: </b>{!relatedTo.Account.AccountNumber}<br/>
                </td>
                <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <apex:outputText value="Date: {0,date,dd' 'MMMM', 'yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />
                    </apex:outputText><br/>
                    <h4>Delivery Address for Return</h4>
                    {!$Organization.Name}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.ShippingStreet}<br/>
                    {!relatedTo.ShippingPostalCode} {!relatedTo.ShippingCity}
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <hr/>

        <table border="0" width="100%" id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Contact name:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Contact email:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Email}<br/>
                    <b>Contact phone:</b> {!relatedTo.CustomerAuthorizedBy.Phone}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Created by:</b> {!relatedTo.CreatedBy.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Source Order :</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Order__r.OrderNumber}<br/>
                    <b>Source Invoice:</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Invoice__r.Name}<br/>
                    <b>Case:</b> {!relatedTo.RMA_Source_Document__c}
                </td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="table3">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Product</h4></td>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Description</h4></td>
    <!--            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Image</h4></td>-->
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Quantity</h4></td>
                <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><h4>Unit</h4></td>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OrderItems}" var="line">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.ProductCode}</td>
                    <td>{!line.Description}</td>
    <!--                    <td ALIGN="center"><img src='{!line.PricebookEntry.Product2.URL_Picture__c}'/></td>             -->
                    <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>
                    <td>{!line.Unit__c}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>  

        </table>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <table width="100%" id="table5">
            <tr>
                <td><b>This is your RMA (Return Maintenance Authority) return form as requested.<br/>
                    THE RMA NUMBER ABOVE MUST BE CLEARLY MARKED ON THE OUTSIDE OF THE PARCEL BEING RETURNED</b>
                    <br/>
                    Please ensure that the goods are sufficiently packaged to ensure that no damage occurs during transit.<br/>
                    If you have any queries or, want to follow up on the collection relating to this return, please contact
                    xxx on <b>0800 999999</b> or <b>email sales@xxx.co.nz</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td alight="center">
                    <h3>Return Reason - please complete</h3>
                    <table border="1" width="95%" height="100px">
                        <tr><td height="100px"></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

</messaging:attachment>      

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further I found an answer here https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gotsAAA in the comments further down (it is not the marked answer!). All that is required to make it work is adding '&new_template=true' to the url hack, so it looks like this now:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?
rtype=003
&p3_lkid={!Order.Id}
&retURL=%2F{!Order.Id}
&template_id=00XO0000000RQ4J
&p5={!$User.Email}
&p2_lkid={!Order.CustomerAuthorizedById}
&new_template=true
```